# do I need to embed navigation controller if I want to make custom navigation bar view?

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I need to make a custom navigation bar, since it will have search bar and some other views, it will be easier if I just make custom view instead of inserting view to navigation controller programatically

like the picture below, there are 2 ways to implement custom navigation bar view, by embedding navigation controller (yellow VCs) and use  or just using present modally segue (blue VCs)

[image]

personally I will choose to use navigation controller because 'maybe' there are some methods that has already built that I can use. but the problem is, the custom navigation view (red color) in navigation controller it seems overlapped by the actual navigation bar in storyboard, I don't know how to hide the navigation bar from navigation controller in storyboard, even though if I use `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)`, it won't be a problem.

what is the right approach to make custom navigation bar like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IB the navigation bar is shown only to simulate what it might look like when you run the app. The decision to show this is inferred, by default, by the fact that it is downstream from the navigation controller. Luckily you can change this option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ken, so I have to use embedded navigation controller ? instead of creating by myself using present modally segue like blue VCs in my image above right ?

Comment: I would recommend that you use it, if you can; But no, you don’t have to.